# How to convert a two-dimensional byte array into a single byte (Arduino)?

Tags: arrays, arduino, binary, byte, converters

I have this array:

> `bool data[]  = {{1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0}};`

And I need to convert it into bool data type like this:

> `byte data = 11110000;`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
#define COLUMNS 2
#define ROWS 4
#define SIZE (COLUMNS * ROWS)


bool data[COLUMNS][ROWS] = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};

byte result = 0;
int shift = SIZE;

for (int i = 0; i < COLUMNS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
        result |= data[i][j] << --shift;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with single loop, for single or multidimensional arrays.

```
bool data[2][4] = { { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

bool *pointer = reinterpret_cast<bool*>(data);
unsigned int value = 0;
for (unsigned int index = 0; index < sizeof(data); ++index) {
    value <<= 1;
    value |= *pointer++;
}
```